# showing both weekdays and weekends on the same fullcalendar

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

I want to show both all days of the week and weekdays as well on the same full calendar.i want to have two button on the calendar one called as "week" which is already on the full calendar which show all day of the week and  other button called as "workweek" which will show me only  weekends after clicking on it.
suggest me for the same.

Here is my code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() { 
  var date = new Date(); 
  var d = date.getDate(); 
  var m = date.getMonth(); 
  var y = date.getFullYear(); 
  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
    header: { 
      left: 'prev,next today', 
      center: 'title', 
       right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month' 
    }, 
    selectable: true, 
    selectHelper: true, 
    weekends:false, 
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek', 
    select: function(start, end, allDay) { //calendar.fullCalendar('unselect'); 
    },
    editable: true 
   }); 
 }); 
</script
```

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
   },
            
   selectable: true,
   selectHelper: true,
            weekends:false,
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
   select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    //calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
   },
   editable: true
  });
 });
</script>

Comment: this is the code for calendar in which i am having three button but i want one extra button called as workweek..after clicking on which i should get weekends only...

Comment: kindly provide me the full code...i am not sure where to define this weekends and workweek in $("weekends")..please help me..

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.but the problem i am facing now that the same code is getting repeated when i am keep on clicking on the each button and the same view keep on adding on the same page means the same calendar appearing many times..so how to solve this..can i use .live(function)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FullCalendar switch between weekends and no weekends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958479/fullcalendar-switch-between-weekends-and-no-weekends)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [FullCalendar switch between weekends and no weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958479/fullcalendar-switch-between-weekends-and-no-weekends)

so this answer only works if you remove the previous copy of the calendar from the DOM

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="weekends" value="Include weekends" />
<input type="button" id="workweek" value="Exclude weekends" />
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
  $("#weekends").on("click",function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({weekends:true});
  });
  $("#workweek").on("click",function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({weekends:false});
  });
});
```

to test my suggestion try pasting this

`javascript:(function() {$('#calendar').fullCalendar({weekends:false})})()`

into the location bar on this page and press enter (in Fx 15+ use the console or create a bookmark)

http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/demos/external-dragging.html